# Why does this Python loop work - a string cannot be less than an integer?

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python and I am going through the free course on python for everybody.
In the course they gave us a question:

Below is code to find the smallest value from a list of values. One line has an error that will cause the code to not work as expected. Which line is it?:

```html
smallest = None
print("Before:", smallest)
for itervar in [3, 41, 12, 9, 74, 15]:
    if smallest is None or itervar < smallest:
        smallest = itervar
        break
    print("Loop:", itervar, smallest)
print("Smallest:", smallest)
```

The answer is line 6.
I am confused as to why line 3 isn't the answer?
smallest = None, but None is a string. Wouldn't the code break because 3 < None would not work? (in the itervar<smallest) part.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, None is a special type and not a string. Line 6 breaks your code prematurely and doesn't check all of the elements in your list. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

`None` isn't a string. It's a special value that signifies a lack of a meaningful value.

But you're right that you can't compare strings and integers or `None` with an integer.

That never happens, though, because `or` short-circuits: if you have `A or B` and `A` is true, then `B` never gets evaluated. So if `smallest is None` then it doesn't compare it to `itervar`, and it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

"None" isn't a string. It specifies that "smallest" currently has no value, similar to being empty.
The first part of the if condition (small is None) is true only once in the first iteration. It then sets "smallest" to "itervar" (3, which in this case is the first number in the list), after this the loop immedietly stops due to the "break" statement, and moves to the 8th line where it prints "Smallest: 3". So the break statement was the problem, which makes the answer line 6.

Answer (score 0):

None isn't a string, it is a python keyword that refers to no value [None in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp)
And no, it wouldn't break.
This is because the 1st condition is checked first. And if `smallest=None`, since it is an `or` block, the second condition doesn't get checked and hence the loop works.
The condition `itervar < smallest` will be checked only if the 1st condition is `False`